# Python: Given a datetime index, remove rows outside of ranges of hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe that is indexed in Datetime format, YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS.
I've resampled it into minute data.
As a result of resampling, it now has filled forward 24 hours worth of data.

What I want to do is remove all the rows that do not fall in time ranges provided.
I have several dataframes with different ranges of times.

For example:

```
Range 1: (0745 - 1410)
Range 2: (1530 - 1755)
Range 3: (2100 - 2300)
```

All the rows within these 3 ranges, I want to keep all the data within. Every row out of these ranges, I want to drop them.

Anybody has any good ideas? I've tried several S/O solutions but none seem to work for my specific case.

Example DF

```
                        Col1       Col2
Datetime                                                                 
2020-04-01 15:00:00     140.1      140.1 
2020-04-01 15:01:00     140.1      140.1
2020-04-01 15:02:00     140.1      140.1
2020-04-01 15:03:00     140.1      140.1
2020-04-01 15:04:00     140.1      140.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. Create a dataframe out of all the ranges, and then merge it with the original dataframe to figure out what are the 'valid' rows:

```
ranges = [
    pd.date_range("07:45", "14:10", freq = "1min"), 
    pd.date_range("15:03", "17:55", freq = "1min"), 
    pd.date_range("21:00", "23:00", freq = "1min"), 
]

valid_times = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(r) for r in ranges])
valid_times[0] = valid_times[0].dt.time
valid_times.columns = ["time"]
valid_times

df["time"] = df.Datetime.dt.time

pd.merge(df, valid_times, on="time")
```

The output in this case:

```
             Datetime   Col1   Col2      time
0 2020-04-01 15:03:00  140.1  140.1  15:03:00
1 2020-04-01 15:04:00  140.1  140.1  15:04:00
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?